# "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" in JSON

Tags: python, json

Ok, so I am having trouble trying to get my code to work, my goal is to make a Reddit Bot that refers to Steam's appid JSON to link users to the steam store page when the user says the name of a game.

The bot is almost complete, however, I keep getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" when the bot runs.

Here is my code:

```
import praw
import time
import json
import codecs

# Death Zone /// I hope you have coffee, brcause you won't leave until this is done

with open('API.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as steam_strings:
    dic = json.loads(steam_strings.read())
    print("Successfully read JSON")


a = dic.get('appid')
n = dic.get('name')

[app['name'] for app in dic['applist']['apps']['app']]


# End Death Zone


app_id = 'CENSORED'
app_secret = 'CENSORED'
app_uri = 'https://127.0.0.1:65010/authorize_callback'
app_ua = 'Stop asking me how to get the Windows flair dummy, I am here for that reason'
app_scopes = 'account creddits edit flair history identity livemanage modconfig modcontributors modflair modlog modothers modposts modself modwiki mysubreddits privatemessages read report save submit subscribe vote wikiedit wikiread'
app_account_code = 'CENSORED'
app_refresh = 'CENSORED'

import praw
def login():
    r = praw.Reddit(app_ua)
    r.set_oauth_app_info(app_id, app_secret, app_uri)
    r.refresh_access_information(app_refresh)
    print("Steam Link Bot! Version Alpha 0.1.2")
    return r

r = login()


words_to_reply = dic['applist']['apps']['app']['name']


# {'applist':1,'apps':2, 'app':3, 'name':4}

cache = []



def run_bot():
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit("eegras")
    comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=100)
    for comment in comments:
        comment_text = comment.body.lower()
        isMatch = any(string in comment_text for string in words_to_reply)
        if comment.id not in cache and isMatch:
            comment.reply(['applist']['apps']['app']['appid'])
            cache.append(comment.id)
            print("I replied to a comment successfully!")



while True:
    run_bot()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm kinda a beginner at Python, so take it easy.

Comment: Can you add what line of code is throwing the error? As the error suggests you are likely trying to index into a list but your are using a `str` type variable instead of an `int`. I suspect it is the line `comment.reply(['applist']['apps']['app']['appid'])` -- this doesn't look like valid python to me, I think you are missing the `dic` variable there

Comment: @TomSitter `['applist']['apps']` **is** valid python Syntax... however it always raises the exact error the OP is getting when run, I highly recommend you post that as an answer as it is very likely the correct solution.

Comment: @TomSitter   

`File "C:\Users\Sean Stevens\Desktop\Reddit Bots!\Steam Bot\obot.py", line 42,

in <module>

    words_to_reply = dic['applist']['apps']['app']['name']

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It's not the multiple indexing I'm talking about, it's that the indexes don't refer to any variable in the code example above.

Comment: @ChoppySean Yeah have a look at your API.json, there must be an array in the structure (look for `[ ]` in the file) so you would have to index by integer at some level (maybe even the top level).

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is raised when it is accessed a list by a string , deferentially of dictionaries that allow be indexed by strings.

If possible comment line which occurs this error, or you can check the type of data making a print type and checking if it really is a dictionary . However make sure the JSON really is structured like a dictionary , or if there are lists inside.